# Handling exceptions in MDI forms

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

C# WinForms: Having a main C# application that can load some other DLLs and show them as MDI forms. So they are all in one thread [STA]
Now if the MDI form crashes for example for a Null reference reason it will cause the whole application to crash and get closed.
What I am looking for is a way to be able to still keep the main application open and running and so it can catch the exception that has occured..is there a way for that? Should I utilize Application.ThreadException in this case? Can you be more specific if that is the route I should take..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Application.ThreadException is what you are looking for, given you have no control over the DLL that are causing the exception.

[Here's a good example on how to implement the methods](http://www.csharp-examples.net/catching-unhandled-exceptions/)

Good Luck!